# How can the performance of LUIS models be improved?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

If you have used the Language Understanding Service (LUIS) which is part of Cognitive Services suite from Microsoft, you probably have come to the point where you needed to improve the performance of your models at predicting intents.

LUIS allows you to train models based on sample utterances which you supply either interactively or in batches. In addition, I would like to have the chat logs showing utterances which are wrongly classified by the model so I can use them as a basis for new training data-sets.

I would imagine that such feature would be released in future but in the meantime, does anyone have a work-around for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to implement this (by hand), would be to route all the messages that were wrongly classified to some kind of storage or log so you could in the future use them to retrain your LUIS model. In fact, you could use LUIS API to make calls dynamically and easily with the data in your log.

So, the flow would be something like this:

1) User send message to bot.

2) Bot logic tries to match message's intent using LUIS model.

3) An intent isn't found or the value associated to the result is really low.

4) Grab that message and store it somewhere (from a simple txt file stored in an Azure Blob Storage), or in in a Database (Table Storage, DocumentDB or SQL Server).

5) Make a simple program that for each line in your log makes you choose an intent and then it calls LUIS Api to retrain.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the closest thing to what I had in mind when I asked the question.

Right on the "MyApps" page on luis.ai there's the possibility to download the chat logs in which one can see the entire set of interactions between users and the bot. It could be a good starting point for picking out intents which were wrongly classified.

[I attached a screenshot to indicate the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z361X.png)

The only caveat is that the log chat format is currently in .csv which isn't so readable. Hopefully LUIS supports json formatted logs soon.